# Understanding osacompile via bash

Tags: applescript

Programmatically I'm trying to create an applescript file on user desktop

I'm trying follow this tutorial here on how to make profile shortcuts on macs: http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/asa/archives/2008/08/shortcut_to_lau.html

So I am doing this by running `/usr/bin/osacompile` with arguments. **Question: is this the right path for osacompile file?**

So next I saw this person who was calling it with some arguments depending on os:

- For Mac OS X 10.4, 10.5, and 10.6 he supplies these arguments:

  - `-o` `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Word Script Menu Items/Zotero/ZoteroQuickLook\\coq.scpt` `scriptDir+"/ZoteroQuickLook\\coq.scpt"`
- For version greater than 10.6 he uses these arguments:

  - `-t` `osas` `-c` `ToyS` `-o` `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Word Script Menu Items/Zotero/ZoteroQuickLook\\coq.scpt` `scriptDir+"/ZoteroQuickLook\\coq.scpt"`

Can you please help me understand what these arguments are doing. Will I use exact same arguments, with different paths, to make the apple script that launches Firefox profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not in the `Open Scripting Architecture` (OSA) itself. The difference between systems is for `Launch Services`. Back in the classic Mac OS days a file type wasn't based on the extension of a file. The file type was based on a file type code. Then there was another code, named creator code that was information in which application the file was created so that once a file was saved by an application, it will be re-opened by the same application. These two codes were stored in the HFS+ file system and was fully supported by Mac OS X until Snow Leopard. After that only the file type code is supported.

I'm not sure in which version of Mac OS X but on Mavericks (and Mountain Lion) it's for sure the creator code and file type code are no longer stored into the HFS+ file system when a script is created using `osacompile`. However it's still supported by AppleScript-editor.app. So when you make a script and want to support this classic Mac OS file type definition you need to explicitly tell `osacompile` to store these two codes into the file system. `osas` is the code to tell it's an Open Scripting Architecture Script, simply called an AppleScript file. the `ToyS` is the creator code for AppleScript-editor (this is ignored since Snow Leopard).

*NOTE: creator and file type codes are case sensitive.*

Comment: I succesfully created an app bundle, but when i click it, it shows erro saying cannot run because it was downloaded by unknown source. Does this have to do with setting creator code wrong? Inoticed you said `ToyS` is ignored since snow leapord, what to use then?

Comment: It's because you saved it as an application. When an application is launched it will lookup the security preferences to your gate keeper settings (see: system preferences). Set the settings in system preferences that you thrust any application, don't save the script as application or code sign your app (please don't ask in the comments here about it, it's starting a whole new topic).

Comment: Thanks man I'll make a new topic on how to code sign. The user is clicking "make desktop shortcut" so they want it there.

Comment: Hey man any alternative to code signing. Only way for me to sign is buying into the paid developer program. The script works just fine when users create and save it from text ScriptEditor, im trying to do same, is there not a creator code for the scripeditor?

Comment: Read more about code signing using key chain keyaccess certificates. Using the command line codesign you're able, with applescript, to code sign the applet.

Comment: I'm struggling with it been trying for two days now :( can you please tell me the answer :( Ill search that though, is that possible without having to purchase any dev stuff?